# How to avoid hard coding file paths?

Tags: vb.net

i need to check if a file exists and if the file exsits then the file should be overwritten.
It works fine if my hard-coded path is used to my own computer but if it is used on another PC there is an error. How can I check this and overwrite the file?

I have asked google for hours but i have not found a solution.

```
Dim gamecfg As String = "\Riot Games\League of Legends\Config\game.cfg"

If System.IO.File.Exists(gamecfg) = True Then    
    on.Visible = True
    off.Visible = True
Else
    MsgBox("Game.cfg was not found", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
    End
End If

Dim gamecfgSON As String = "\Riot Games\League of Legends\Config\game.cfg"
Dim cfgWriterSON As New System.IO.StreamWriter(gamecfgSON)

cfgWriterSON.Write(RichTextBox1.Text)
cfgWriterSON.Close()
```

So if the file is located for an example in: E:\Games\League of Legends\
then it says Game.cfg was not found

I hope you can help me.

Comment: Are you asking how to handle League of Legends not being installed to `E:`?  Or if it uses a different hierarchy than ``\Games\League of Legends\`` entirely?  Would searching for a `game.cfg` file in a ``Config\`` directory suffice?  Or just prompting the user for its location?

Comment: I fixed your code formatting.  Please do us the courtesy of ensuring that your code is as readable as possible, which includes consistent indenting and also ensuring that you don't miss a trailing double-quote (which would prevent your code form compiling, so it's obviously the wrong to be posting in the first place) so that the syntax highlighting is all messed up.  You're provided with a preview for a reason.  Don't submit until the preview looks correct.

Comment: Any code that includes `End` is bad code.  There are better ways to exit an application than that.

Comment: We don't put "solved" in the question.  You've accepted an answer, that's good enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can usually locate files in one of several ways:

1. Pull the info from the registry.
2. Try most obvious combinations of paths.
3. Heuristic search.
4. Ask the user.

**Heuristic search:** Search all folders on all drives for "Riot Games' and 'League of Legends'. Limit search depth and avoid obvious traps like 'Windows*', '$Recycle.Bin', etc.). Usually you'd make several iterations, like first searching only in folders with 'game' in the name.

Answer (score 1):

You have several possibilities:

- Check whether the game writes any registry key that contains the path. If that is the case, chances are high that the names of the registry key in the same everywhere.
- Ask the user in a dialog where the file is, suggesting the default installation path.
- Let your application be called with a command line parameter that contains the according path.
- Search the drives, but that is probably gonna be terribly slow.

Answer (score 0):

try to find out parentpath
File dir = new File( System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/.")
String parentPath = dir.getParentFile().getName()